# Accessing retrofit 2 data outside on response?

Tags: list, retrofit2

I am working on two apps, in one of my app "A" i applied retrofit 2.

This was the method i used to retrieve data.

But here in on Response  the data retrieved in response body can be set to activity variables and can be used outside this method without getting null values.

```
  public void fetch_information() {
            ApiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);

            Call<List<City>> call = ApiInterface.GetCities();


            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<City>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<City>> call, Response<List<City>> response) {
                    citylist = new ArrayList<City>();
                    citylist = response.body();  
                    cities = new String[citylist.size()];
                    citiesid = new String[citylist.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < citylist.size(); i++) {
                        cities[i] = citylist.get(i).getCityName();
                        citiesid[i] = citylist.get(i).getCityId();


                    }

                    city_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pay_Payment_X.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
                    city_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_layout);
                    City_Spinner.setAdapter(city_adapter);


                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<City>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
```

after applying this method and on debugging this method i will retain values of varaibles "cities" and "citiesid"out side onResponse.

But applying retrofit 2 similarly on another app "B", i did the same thing for retrieving data on different URL.

```
ApiUtil.getServiceClass().getAllPost().enqueue(new Callback<List<ApiObject>>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<ApiObject>> call, Response<List<ApiObject>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<ApiObject> postList = response.body();


                            try {

                                for (int i = 0; i < postList.size(); i++) {
                                    String Name = postList.get(i).getGamesName();
                                    mGamesName.add(Name);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }

                        Log.d(TAG, "Returned count " + postList.size());
                        NewAdapter adapter = new NewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), postList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<ApiObject>> call, Throwable t) {
                    //showErrorMessage();
                    Log.d(TAG, "error loading from API");
                }

            });
```

the data is retrievable inside onResponse but outside it shows null.
So here variables are not retaining values.

Why is this happening?

the only thing came to mind is retrieving data can take time while your code lines are being read and finding null values as data has not been received yet.

Also to mention in app "A" the data retrieved is huge but in app "B" only 3 objects with string values.But still in app"A" data is retrievable.

In app 2 did this for resolving my issue.

```
public void doRequest( final ApiCallback callback){

        ApiUtil.getServiceClass().getAllPost().enqueue(new Callback<List<ApiObject>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ApiObject>> call, Response<List<ApiObject>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<ApiObject> postList = response.body();
                    callback.onSuccess(postList);
                    // apobject =response.body();
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {

                            for (int i = 0; i < postList.size(); i++) {
                                String Name = postList.get(i).getGamesName().toString();
                                mGamesName.add(Name);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Returned count " + postList.size());
                    NewAdapter adapter = new NewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), postList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ApiObject>> call, Throwable t) {
                //showErrorMessage();
                Log.d(TAG, "error loading from API");
            }

        });


    }
```

pass an interface

```
 public interface ApiCallback{
        void onSuccess(List<ApiObject> result);
    }
```

and in on Create view of activity i called this

```
 doRequest(new ApiCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<ApiObject> result){
                //here i can set variable values
            }
        });
```

Comment: can any one explain more in depth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the only thing came to mind is retrieving data can take time while your code lines are being read and finding null values as data has not been received yet.

That's entirely correct. Your call is finishing after you check the values. I'm going to go on a limb here and say that it's just a coincidence that it works on one app and not in the other (if they are actually doing it the same way)

When you call `callback.onSuccess(postList);` doesn't seem to be right either, because you haven't checked yet for success. This means that `response.body()` might be `null` and `response.errorBody()` will contain the body of the error.

If you'd move `callback.onSuccess` inside the `if` this would be fixed:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
    callback.onSuccess(response.body());
    try {
            for (int i = 0; i < postList.size(); i++) {
                String Name = postList.get(i).getGamesName().toString();
                mGamesName.add(Name);
             }
    } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Last but not least, inside the `onSuccess` method is when you can use your global variables. Maybe it's better to stop using global variables and just use the callback parameters.

Comment: i actually did callback after response is successful but my interest in not here as it solved my problem. Can you tell me about the code i mentioned above where in app"A" i am able to access variables but in app"B" same code cannot access variables "tell the difference about them". The last part of code with callback.success is understandable for me.And by global variable you mean in activity or application , because i want to provide values to activity variables from inside on response data.

Comment: Like you said, it's asynchronously called. It's possible that it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. If you want to access these values somewhere else, then you need to do it from callbacks like you have `onSuccess`. This is the only time when you're sure the values will be there.